# Issue while running Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This message is appearing when I run Selenium

Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 53398
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Jul 14, 2023 2:25:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected upstream dialect: W3C
Jul 14, 2023 2:25:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 114, so returning the closest version found: a no-op implementation
Jul 14, 2023 2:25:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 114.
Jul 14, 2023 2:25:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$3
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for . You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.3.0` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.

Not sure how to proceed with this.

The website is opening, but getting crashed within few seconds.

Comment: I have been running this locally using Eclipse. I have setup Java JDK, Chrome Driver and added all Selenium JAR files to the project